# queue entries of threadpool in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

I am trying to implement a thredpool, and I found that there are two implementations. They are all using queue to manage tasks, but the entries of queue are different. I want to konw which is more better and the rational of the implementations. Why the second version need a `function_wrapper`.

First version use `std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()> > tasks;`

```
class ThreadPool {
 public:
  explicit ThreadPool(size_t);
  template <class F, class... Args>
  decltype(auto) enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args);
  ~ThreadPool();

 private:
  // need to keep track of threads so we can join them
  std::vector<std::thread> workers;
  // the task queue
  std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()> > tasks;

  // synchronization
  std::mutex queue_mutex;
  std::condition_variable condition;
  bool stop;
};

// add new work item to the pool
template <class F, class... Args>
decltype(auto) ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  using return_type = decltype(f(args...));

  std::packaged_task<return_type()> task(
      std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));

  std::future<return_type> res = task.get_future();
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);

    // don't allow enqueueing after stopping the pool
    if (stop) throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");

    tasks.emplace(std::move(task));
  }
  condition.notify_one();
  return res;
}
```

Second version use `thread_safe_queue<function_wrapper> work_queue;`

```
class function_wrapper {
  struct impl_base {
    virtual void call() = 0;
    virtual ~impl_base() {}
  };
  std::unique_ptr<impl_base> impl;
  template <typename F>
  struct impl_type : impl_base {
    F f;
    impl_type(F&& f_) : f(std::move(f_)) {}
    void call() { f(); }
  };

 public:
  template <typename F>
  function_wrapper(F&& f) : impl(new impl_type<F>(std::move(f))) {}
  void operator()() { impl->call(); }
  function_wrapper() = default;
  function_wrapper(function_wrapper&& other) : impl(std::move(other.impl)) {}
  function_wrapper& operator=(function_wrapper&& other) {
    impl = std::move(other.impl);
    return *this;
  }
  function_wrapper(const function_wrapper&) = delete;
  function_wrapper(function_wrapper&) = delete;
  function_wrapper& operator=(const function_wrapper&) = delete;
};

class thread_pool {
  thread_safe_queue<function_wrapper> work_queue;
  void worker_thread() {
    while (!done) {
      function_wrapper task;
      if (work_queue.try_pop(task)) {
        task();
      } else {
        std::this_thread::yield();
      }
    }
  }

 public:
  template <typename FunctionType>
  std::future<typename std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type> submit(
      FunctionType f) {
    typedef typename std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type result_type;
    std::packaged_task<result_type()> task(std::move(f));
    std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
    work_queue.push(std::move(task));
    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: For discussions about pros and cons of different (valid) approaches, you may have more luck at CodeReview stackexchange. Also, your own use cases will be very pertinent to what the "best" solution for you is. The less synchronization you can get away with, the better, for example. Or perhaps you need to perform type-erasure, or perhaps not.

Comment: `class function_wrapper` basically implements `std::function<void()>`. There's not reason to do that, so first version is better (less code = less bugs).

Comment: @rustyx but why `std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()> > tasks;` can take any type of functions

Comment: @ywen232625 because [`std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) already wraps the task like `std::function` does. "*The class template `std::packaged_task` wraps any `Callable` target (function, lambda expression, bind expression, or another function object) so that it can be invoked asynchronously.*".